# Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.(Flutter)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Hi I have a scenario where in I enter the username password    based on the credentials it will redirect the user to second screen  . I am not sure where did I got wrong? but I am getting this error below:
Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.

Here is the code:

```html
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'Animation/FadeAnimation.dart';
import 'AuthenticationService.dart';
import 'PatientList.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  gotoPatientList(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>PatientList()),
    );
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
          context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        ),
      ],
      child:MaterialApp(
        home: SingleChildScrollView(
          child:RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              gotoPatientList(context);
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 400,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/loginHeader.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FadeAnimation(
                            1.8,
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color:
                                        Color.fromRGBO(143, 148, 251, .2),
                                        blurRadius: 20.0,
                                        offset: Offset(0, 10))
                                  ]),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        border: Border(
                                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.grey[100]))),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: emailController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          hintText: "Email or Phone number",
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: TextField(
                                      controller: passwordController,
                                      obscureText: true,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          hintText: "Password",
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.grey[400])),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        FadeAnimation(
                            2,
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                    Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                                  ])),
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "Login",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 70,
                        ),
                        FadeAnimation(
                            1.5,
                            Text(
                              "Forgot Password?",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      return HomePage();
    }
    return PatientList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the button in builder to get the context of the app:

```
Builder(
    builder: (context) => RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              gotoPatientList(context);
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signIn(
                email: emailController.text.trim(),
                password: passwordController.text.trim(),
              );
            },
            ...
    ),
);
```